# JAVA class not found but declared among the imports

Tags: java, netbeans, javaimports

I had declared and implemented a class (1) in a package , then imported (2) and used (3) in another class file of the same package but not folder :

1 - `class file MIkController has no problem or warning`

2 - `import pro.gcon.mik.controller.MIkController;`

3 - `public void setController(MIkController miKController) { #body }`

Class MIkController is in `package pro.gcon.mik.controller` , while the class file where i need to use `MIkController` is in `package pro.gcon.mik.view` .
Everything worked until i closed NetBeans , the next time i had found that the import (2) appeared as not used and it tells me that the declared function (3) needs one class , enum , etc. I've tried to found an answer but I have not found anything that is right for my problem. Sorry for my school English and thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with javac directly? If that works then it's an issue with the IDE/project setup rather than the code in file (3).

Comment: Also, try commenting out the import and instead use the fully qualified class name everywhere it appears in the file. If you're seeing a problem after doing that, it may be for example that you're using a different version of the imported class than intended.

Comment: I tried the fully qualified name and the javac compiling but nothing change (javac : invalid flag) , for the second one i don't know but i have only 6 files divided in 3 folder , all of that with different names like MIkPanel , ButPanel or MIField .